# Assign static value to class from another class

Tags: c#

My question is pretty much basic but I am not getting idea to do it. Please check the code bellow. My basic goal is to make a public class which will return some static data under a list. The example class model is provided bellow. See in class `PaymentMethodDetials` has two properties and I want to set value of this two property from class `PaymentMethodList` as a list then I will be using those list values outside this whole c# class model publically. Now my problem is `paymentList.Add()` visual studio not allowing me to do `Add` method. How can I fix that? Thanks in advance

```
namespace Test.Helpers
{
    public class PaymentMethodList
    {

        List<PaymentMethodDetials> paymentList = new List<PaymentMethodDetials>();
        paymentList.Add()//i want to insert data to "PaymentMethodDetials" this class like using "Add" which allowing now
    }

    public class PaymentMethodDetials
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Add(...)` takes a parameter.  You aren't passing in anything.

Comment: Yes i want to pass `Id` and `Name` but visual studio not make `Add` available under intellisense

Comment: Please advice me better solution to get and set value statically

Comment: You can't put that code directly in the class. It has to belong to a method, such as a constructor. But don't make a class called `PaymentMethodList` in the first place. You already have `List<PaymentMethod>` Just make that list a static member of the existing class, and use a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) when you declare it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this , hope this helps

```js
namespace Test.Helpers
    {
        public class PaymentMethodList
        {

            List<PaymentMethodDetials> paymentList = new List<PaymentMethodDetial();
            public PaymentMethodList()
            {
               paymentList.Add(new PaymentMethodDetials
              {
                Id=1,
                Name="xyz"
              });
            }
           
        }

        public class PaymentMethodDetials
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Now check my updated answer, You are trying to initialize directly in class, try to add data in constructor or some other methods

Comment: Thanks. Works now